# php GD graphic does not produce the expected results

Tags: php, gd

I am running ubuntu and have a simple script to test gd but it doesn't seem to work. The script below generates a black screen with a 16x16 empty box in the middle of the screen. There are no errors. Developer console on google chrome doesn't show any errors. Also the phpinfo() for GD appears everything is good.

I added this to the php.ini and dont see any errors

```
display_startup_errors = On
Set error_log = '/var/log/php-error.log'
```

This is the script that makes a 16x16 blank square

```
    <?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
$im = @imagecreate (800, 400) or die ( "cannot create a new gd image.");
 $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 240, 240, 240);
 $border_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 50, 50, 50);
 $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 233, 14, 91);

 imagerectangle($im,0,0,199,99,$border_color);
 imagestring ($im, 5, 10, 40, "a simple text string", $text_color );
header ("content-type: image/png");
imagepng ($im);
?>
```

Comment: PHP open Tag `<?php` needs to be **very first** to have no prefixed whitespaces. Remove PHP close tag at the end. `?>`. Maybe you need to `echo imagepng($im);`.

Comment: The space at the start fixed it! I am blind. Thank you!